# replacing comma with linebreak in a string in an uib-alert doenst work

Tags: html, angularjs, alert, line-breaks, uib

I have a string with lots of  `"` which i replace with an empty String and this works.
But I also want to make a line break when a comma appears.

Already tried it with `('\n')`, `('\r')`, `('<br>')`, `('<br/>')` but nothing works.
in my angular controller I have the string

```
self.msg = msg.replace(/"/gi, '').replace(/,/gi, '\n'); 
self.testAlerts = [{ type: 'success', msg: self.msg}];
```

I want to show this message in the alert box in my html

```
<div uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in testAlerts" type="{{alert.type}}" >{{alert.msg}}</div>
```

Why do the line breaks not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-bind-html instead of interpolation:

```
<div uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in testAlerts" type="{{alert.type}}" ng-bind-html="alert.msg"></div>
```

Here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7Y1V0bp8Uru7raQ5cBhf?p=preview) for demonstration.

Comment: this gives me the error : "Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

Comment: Use $sce.trustAsHtml in your controller code. I updated the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7Y1V0bp8Uru7raQ5cBhf?p=preview)

Comment: really great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody from Angular world is happen to be here you can use 
    [innerHTML] instead of [ng-bind-html] from @RamblinRose's answer

Or even,  just add css white-space class

```
<div uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in testAlerts" style="white-space: pre-line;" type="{{alert.type}}" >{{alert.msg}}</div>
```